# How to set default value of dropdownlist onclick of another dropdownlist using jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two dropdown lists. On click of one dropdown,i want to set a default value in another dropdown and then disabling the dropdown.

Eg: Two dropdown lists are Dropdownlist1 and Dropdownlist2. Suppose I select a value from Dropdownlist1 then a default value in Dropdownlist2 should be selected and then Dropdownlist2 should be disabled.

```
function checkForEnable(tes, x){
    var dropdown2= "#abc_".concat(tes).concat("_").concat(x);
    var dropdown1= "#xyz_".concat(tes).concat("_").concat(X);
    if($(dropdown1).val()=="1"){
             $(dropdown2).val('-1').attr("selected", "selected");
             $(dropdown2).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

     }
}
```

This is the piece of code I wrote. I select the default option from dropdown1 and then i want the deafult value of dropdown2 to be selected and then disabled.

Comment: Can you show us the code what you have tried so far? In a jsfiddle if possible

Comment: Please supply html and javascript to show us what you have tried already, and explain what is wrong with it.  This is not a "write my code for me" site.

Comment: Please give your code that you tried.

Comment: Who on earth up-voted this question?  I would *love* a good reason why someone would do that.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your id attributes are Dropdownlist1 and Dropdownlist2:

```
$('#Dropdownlist1').on('change', function() {
    // Your desired logic to examine $('#Dropdownlist1').val() and decide what value you want in the second one
    $('#Dropdownlist2').val('selectedvalue');
    $('#Dropdownlist2').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: Disabled is a property - use `.prop()` ;)

Comment: Right you are! Updated.